# Testflight internal group?

Tags: ios, testflight, internal

Can I create an internal group in testflight. We have 2 different builds of our app that we want to test and the app isn't ready yet to be reviewed by Apple for external testing. For example: the login does nothing, you need a separate piece of hardware to test it, etc...

Comment: If your app is dependent on hardware then probably you can mention it in the notes and let Apple review it for your test flight.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally you have an "iTunes Connect Users" group with the people register on you iTunes account like developers, admins and so on.

You also have an "External Testers" group with a possibility to add 2.000 emails to the people outside of the iTunes account.

You just need to create another group (you'll find a button with this text "NEW GROUP") and add the people to test that features and each time you upload a new build you add the group by clicking on the build that you want to test your app.

I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Not really, cause I can't add users to that group that already are added in the iTunes connect users group which basically are all our testers. And if it's added to a group that isn't the iTunes Connect Users than I need to send it to apple to review it.

Comment: @KamilKulach I'm curious about this, why did you accept the answer? It's clearly not answering your question (which is the same I have right now).